# Javascript object vs var/array

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

I'm learning JavaScript/HTML/CSS and I have this:

My Question is, does it matter if I do it this way or with an array or with 3 vars? I simply did it this way because I think it looks better, but I wonder what the "best" or "right" way to do it is. With arrays I could only access the numbers with kzh[0], kzh[1], kzh[2], right? I think with arrays it looks a lot more confusing, because you don't know what the numbers stand for, especially if it gets more complex than my little homework.

```
var kzh = {
    High: 0,
    Medium: 0,
    Low: 0
};

function addKZH(x) {
    kzh[x]++;
    alert(kzh[x]);
}
```

And this feels redundant to me..

```
var kzhHigh = 0;
var kzhMedium = 0;
var kzhLow = 0;

function addKZHhigh() {

    kzhHigh++;
    alert(kzhHigh);
}
function addKZHmedium() {

    kzhMedium++;
    alert(kzhMedium);
}
function addKZHlow() {

    kzhLow++;
    alert(kzhLow);
}
```

Comment: a) You're right. b) It's a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: I think that the object verison  looks better if you use prototype hineritance

Comment: You might want to utilize Code Review site for the same https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @gurvinder372 i didn't even know that existed!

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering about performance issues or something like that. And thanks @gurvinder372 for sharing that site!

Comment: Unless you have the same logic to be applied to every item of the array, there is no point in keeping this in array. On the other hand, if same logic applies to all the values in the array then there it makes sense in refactoring the same and keep a single array variable for iteration.

Comment: how do you now, which of `high`, `medium` or `low` to use?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have 3 images with onclick events, image one triggers "addKZH('High')", image two triggers "addKZH('Medium') and image three triggers "addKZH('Low').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  with arrays it becomes confusing as you have access to only indices and not the variable/property's name.

However it is correct to use in both the manners using object's properties as well as independent variables and functions. But in programming we always look for **code reusability** and using 3 functions for similar task is not a good idea. Also since the variables are also related we can make them a single object's properties to *reduce the number of variables, improve readability and show a relation* among them. So using object is the way I would recommend.

```
var kzh = {
    High:0,
    Medium:0,
    Low:0
};

function addKZH(x) {
        kzh[x]++;
        alert(kzh[x]);
}

addKZH("High");
addKZH("Medium");
addKZH("Low");
```

Answer (score 0):

Array in javascript not only using number for key.

`var kzh = {High:0, Medium:0, Low:0};
kzh['High']++;
alert(JSON.stringify(kzh));`

output --> {High:1, Medium:0, Low:0}
https://jsfiddle.net/wmuev1a7/